# Нужен ли lock в этом коде?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Подскажите пожалуйста нужен ли lock в этом коде, если я собираюсь использовать его в Parallel.ForEach?
Пример кода с lock:

```
private IEnumerable<(Byte[] part_bytes, Int32 part_number)> GetPartsFile(FileStream file_stream)
    {
        file_stream.Seek(offset: 0, origin: SeekOrigin.Begin);
        for (Int32 index = 0, part_number = 0; index < file_stream.Length; index += DefaultCopyBufferSize, part_number++)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[DefaultCopyBufferSize];
                Int32 readed_bytes = file_stream.Read(array: bytes, offset: index, count: DefaultCopyBufferSize);
                if (readed_bytes < DefaultCopyBufferSize)
                {
                    Byte[] end_bytes = new Byte[readed_bytes];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(src: bytes, srcOffset: 0, dst: end_bytes, dstOffset: 0, count: readed_bytes);
                    yield return (end_bytes, part_number);
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return (bytes, part_number);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Пример использования в Parallel.ForEach:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
source: GetPartsFile(file_stream: zip_file),
body: tuple =>
{
    //тут ещё какие то действия
});
```

Comment: Нет, не нужен: `source` выполняется в одном потоке, а вот `body` - может в нескольких. И вот ещё что: за `lock(this)` в приличном обществе бьют канделябром...

Comment: У меня кстати код с lock не стал работать, выдаёт исключение SynchronizationLockException. Я так понимаю из-за того что yield return не освобождает lock...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, если оформите ответ, отмечу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именно для работы метода `Parallel.ForEach` оператор `lock` в этом коде не нужен.

Параметр `source` - источник - выполняется в одном потоке. А вот `body` - тело - может выполняться в нескольких потоках (а может и в одном).

---

Отмечу, что блокировака на `this` является опасной. Если кто-либо ещё возьмёт лок на этот же объект этого класса, то это может привести к дедлоку.

Answer (score 4):

По поводу `SynchronizationLockException`. Ваш метод возвращает `IEnumerable`. Когда вы указываете этот метод в качестве источника данных для `Parallel.ForEach()`, это значит, что разные элементы последовательности могут быть запрошены и обработаны разными потоками.

Но тут в дело вступает `yield return`. При наличии такой конструкции итератор работает немного по-другому:

1. Метод начинает выполняться, происходит первая итерация цикла.
2. Метод возвращает первый элемент последовательности, *при этом первая итерация цикла еще не закончена*.
3. При запросе следующего элемента завершается первая итерация, начинается вторая, возвращается второй элемент. Вторая итерация при этом тоже не закончена.
4. И так по кругу.

Теперь если скомбинировать `Parallel.ForEach()`, `yield return` и `lock`, получим такой сценарий:

1. Первый поток запрашивает первый элемент: выполняется первая итерация цикла, захватывается лок, возвращается первый элемент. *Лок не освобождается*.
2. Второй поток запрашивает следующий элемент: завершается первая итерация, код пытается освободить лок и мы получаем исключение `SynchronizationLockException`, которое говорит о том, что поток попытался вызвать метод монитора, которым он не владеет. Потому что в монитор входил первый поток, а выйти из него пытается второй поток.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения, стало теперь более понятно почему так происходит. Плюсую вам ответ)

Comment: @ИванК не за что!